# System of Equations and determinants

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Consider the system $2x+ay=s$ and $3ax+6y=t$. For which values of a will the system have a unique solution using determinants?

Comment: Show please your attempts.

Comment: [How to ask a homework question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1803/how-to-ask-a-homework-question)

Answer (score 0):

Remember that any system of equations $\,A\vec x=\vec b$ over a field has a unique solution **if and only if** $det(A)\neq0$

In your case, what will $A$ be?